# SetState is not working on react-dropdown-tree-select

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, react-dropdown-tree-select

I am attempting to implement a tree dropdown in a React application using the 'react-dropdown-tree-select' package, and it worked without issue until we attempted to change the state.

```jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import DropdownTreeSelect from 'react-dropdown-tree-select';
import 'react-dropdown-tree-select/dist/styles.css';

function TreeDropDown(props) {
  const { tree_unit_data, handleTreeUnitListChange } = props;
  const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState(tree_unit_data);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the treeData when tree_unit_data prop changes
    setTreeData(tree_unit_data);
  }, [tree_unit_data]);

  const onChange = (currentNode, selectedNodes) => {
    // Handle the onChange event here
    handleTreeUnitListChange(selectedNodes) //This will break the DropdownTreeSelect and if we comment this it work
  };

  return (
    <DropdownTreeSelect
      data={treeData}
      onChange={onChange}
      texts={{ placeholder: 'Select Node' }}
    />
  );
}

export default TreeDropDown;
```

I even attempted to set the state in this component, and it also yielded the same result

```jsx
const onChange = (currentNode, selectedNodes) => {
  // Handle the onChange event here
  setTreeUnits(selectedNodes)
};
```

Somehow, it gets re-rendered whenever the state changes. I am somewhat blocked by this issue, and I would greatly appreciate it if someone could assist in identifying and resolving the problem.

[image]

Getting above exception as well when clicking on the dropdown

For testing purpose this data can be used

```js
const treeData = [
  {
    label: 'Node 1',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Node 1.1',
      },
      {
        label: 'Node 1.2',
        children: [
          {
            label: 'Node 1.2.1',
          },
          {
            label: 'Node 1.2.2',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: 'Node 2',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Node 2.1',
      },
      {
        label: 'Node 2.2',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

React Version : 18.2
Node Version: 18.15.0
NPM Version: 9.5.0

Comment: wt's the value of tree_unit_data ?

Comment: Do you want the actual structure of the dropdown to change whenever you select an option within it, or just to show that an item has been selected/deselected?

Comment: wha is handleTreeUnitListChange method doing, is there any chance you could share that.

Comment: Minimal working example would be great. Stackblitz for example.

Answer (score 1):

I am quite confused. If `tree_unit_data` can trigger a `useEffect`, why not just simply pass the prop? The added hoop of using a `useEffect` seems unncessary. It is also highly frowned upon by React. See [You Might Not Need an Effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect).

The warning you are getting is simply because `TreeDropDown` was written as a React Class Component and it is attempting to manipulate the lifecycle. Unless React decides to break all pre-`React16.0.0` code, you can ignore the warning.

However, your problem is not `TreeDropDown`. It is more likely to do with how your `handleTreeUnitListChange` is manipulating state. Since you have not provided enough data on how it works, I cannot really provide you with a clearly helpful answer on why your solution is not working. Here is a working demo with your data and `TreeDropDown`:

```
import "./styles.css";
import tree from "./tree.json";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DropdownTreeSelect from "react-dropdown-tree-select";
import "react-dropdown-tree-select/dist/styles.css";

function DropDownTree(props) {
  const { tree_unit_data, handleTreeUnitListChange } = props;
  const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState(tree_unit_data);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the treeData when tree_unit_data prop changes
    setTreeData(tree_unit_data);
    // console.log(ree)
  }, [tree_unit_data]);

  const onChange = (currentNode, selectedNodes) => {
    // Handle the onChange event here
    handleTreeUnitListChange(selectedNodes);
  };

  return (
    <DropdownTreeSelect
      data={treeData}
      onChange={onChange}
      texts={{ placeholder: "Select Node" }}
      value={treeData}
    />
  );
}
export default function App() {
  const [tree_data, set_tree_data] = React.useState(tree);
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  // Assign nodes a checked value based on changes in the tree
  // This is recomputed every time and is not really a good
  // implementation, especially if the tree is large.
  function handleTreeUnitListChange(selectedNodes) {
    set_tree_data((tree) => {
      const newTree = tree;
      const selectedNodesLabels = selectedNodes.map((e) => e.label);
      function recursiveFindAndUpdateTree(some_tree) {
        if (!some_tree || some_tree.length === 0) return;
        some_tree.forEach((e) => {
          if (selectedNodesLabels.includes(e.label)) {
            e.checked = true;
          } else {
            e.checked = false;
          }
          recursiveFindAndUpdateTree(e.children);
        });
      }
      recursiveFindAndUpdateTree(newTree);
      // No re-render
      return newTree;
    });
  }

  function toggleNode2WithoutRerender() {
    const newTree = tree_data;
    newTree[1].checked = !newTree[1].checked;
    newTree[1].children[0].checked = !newTree[1].children[0].checked;
    newTree[1].children[1].checked = !newTree[1].children[1].checked;
    set_tree_data(newTree);
  }

  function toggleNode2AndRerender() {
    toggleNode2WithoutRerender();
    set_tree_data((tree) => [...tree]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DropDownTree
        tree_unit_data={tree_data}
        handleTreeUnitListChange={handleTreeUnitListChange}
      />
      {/* State will update when clicked but because we are not recreating the object no re-render will happen */}
      <button onClick={toggleNode2WithoutRerender}>
        Try to toggle node 2 (will fail because we are not re-rendering)
      </button>
      <div />
      <button onClick={toggleNode2AndRerender}>
        Try to toggle node 2 (will work because we are re-rendering)
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can see it here: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-elgamal-nlxzjh?file=/src/App.js)

```html
<iframe src="https://codesandbox.io/embed/lucid-elgamal-nlxzjh?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=preview"
     style="width:100%; height:500px; border:0; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden;"
     title="lucid-elgamal-nlxzjh"
     allow="accelerometer; ambient-light-sensor; camera; encrypted-media; geolocation; gyroscope; hid; microphone; midi; payment; usb; vr; xr-spatial-tracking"
     sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
   ></iframe>
```

TL;DR If your goal is to have control of `DropDownTreeSelect` using state, remember to clone the tree on state changes. If you do not want to cause a re-render and want to use `DropDownTreeSelect` internal state manager, simply modify the state in place. If you want to update a state based on the selection and cause a re-render in a consumer of that state but not `DropDownTreeSelect`, simply do not pass the manipulated state as a prop to `DropDownTreeSelect` or its parent. If you want to pass it as a prop, consider looking into their official docs on how to do that [here](https://github.com/dowjones/react-dropdown-tree-select/blob/main/docs/HOC.md#prevent-re-render-on-parent-prop-state-changes).

Answer (score 0):

Don't set state inside a `useEffect` hook. It can cause infinite loops since setting state will cause a re-render, which will in turn trigger `useEffect`, and so on.

It's difficult to answer your question without knowing exactly what `handleTreeUnitListChange()` does. I will make the huge assumption that it's storing `selectedNodes` in a parent component and then rendering `data` with `checked` properties depending on whether the user just selected or unselected that node.

If that's indeed the case, you don't need to use state in this component at all! Delete the line where you call `useState()` and your entire `useEffect()` callback.

If that's not the case, you should store the `data` state in somewhere it makes sense to do that and modify it based on the return value of `onChange()`. It could even be in this component. Make sure that objects in `data` that have been selected have the `checked` property.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I don't feel a state is even required. You can directly pass `treeData` as follows. And write this line in your component. And remove current `useEffect` to setState which is rendering in an infinite loop.

```
const treeData = React.useMemo(() => props.tree_unit_data, [props.tree_unit_data]);

<DropdownTreeSelect
  data={treeData}
  onChange={onChange}
  texts={{ placeholder: 'Select Node' }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try move "setTreeData(tree_unit_data);" to "componentDidUpdate logic" as here:

```
const mounted = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  if (!mounted.current) {
    // do componentDidMount logic
    mounted.current = true;
  } else {
    // do componentDidUpdate logic
    setTreeData(tree_unit_data);
  }
}, [tree_unit_data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are replacing the `tree_unit_data` reference when changing the data. You are watching `tree_unit_data` as a reference, so if you change the contents within it, the reference does not change. Basically clone the `tree_unit_data` and then use `setTreeData(new_tree_unit_data)`, or add dependencies on the underlying values of this object.